# MariaDB Container is not getting up of Frappe Docker

Tags: docker, mariadb, containers, frappe

Trying to containerized ERPNext using Frappe_Docker

MariaDB Container is not running as getting below error

```
2023-05-01 00:07:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 started.
2023-05-01 00:07:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-05-01 00:07:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 started.
2023-05-01 00:07:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.12-MariaDB-1:10.6.12+maria~ubu2004 source revision 4c79e15cc3716f69c044d4287ad2160da8101cdc as process 1
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=89965477,89965477
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 89965477 between the checkpoint 89965477 and the end 89965489.
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-05-01  0:07:16 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

tried to various methods but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like data corruption due to two MariaDB instances running on the same data directory. This resulted in the [error (MDEV-28976)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28976). While this has an earlier than 10.6.12 version its quite possible that the error occurred on a previous startup, or if under the current startup with another MariaDB instance already started or shutting down. Never versions re-introduced some protection around this.

Unfortunately for you, a restore from backup is required.